# Distance Calculation Not Returning Results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distance

Code from `api.php`:

```
    $lat = $_GET['lat'];
    $lng = $_GET['lon'];

    try {$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);}
    catch(PDOException $e){echo($e->getMessage());}

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *, (POW(69.1 * (`lat` - :lat), 2) +
                            POW(69.1 * (:lon - `long`) * COS(`lat` / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
                            FROM `venues` HAVING distance < SQRT(16) ORDER BY distance");
    $stmt->bindParam(':lat', $lat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lon', $lon, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    $venues = array();
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $venues[] = $row;       
            echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . json_encode($venues);
        }
    }
```

This returns nothing when visiting `api.php?lat=LAT_VALUE&lon=LON_VALUE`.

However, when I type into SQL the following:

```
SELECT * , (
POW( 69.1 * (`lat`-'LAT_VALUE'),2) + POW(69.1*('LON_VALUE'-`long`)*COS(`lat`/57.3),2)) AS distance
FROM  `venues` 
HAVING distance < SQRT( 16 ) 
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

...it returns results just fine.

What's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two names for the `$lon` / `$lng` variable.
Try this instead:

```
$lon = $_GET['lon'];
```

Comment: I... I have no excuse. Thanks for pointing out in one minute what I couldn't find in thirty. I need some sleep!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in here . You are using `:lon` instead of `lng` in query

```
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *, (POW(69.1 * (`lat` - :lat), 2) +
                POW(69.1 * (:lon - `long`) * COS(`lat` / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
                  FROM `venues` HAVING distance < SQRT(16) ORDER BY distance");
```

Use instead

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *, (POW(69.1 * (`lat` - :lat), 2) +
                  POW(69.1 * (:lng - `long`) * COS(`lat` / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
                   FROM `venues` HAVING distance < SQRT(16) ORDER BY distance");
```